# How to fix this regex (matching dictionary entries)

Tags: java, regex, parsing

I am working with a spanish dictionary that has definitions like the following:

```
l. a. c. Buitre, alimoche. adj. Persona alelada. (Cornago). GOICOECHEA. // 2. f. Persona torpe, despistada e irreflexiva. // 3. Estar mirando a los abantos. fr. fig. Ser despistado, soñador, no apercibirse de la realidad. Autol. RUIZ. // 4. f. esto es una prueba
```

Where the following rules apply:

- Each definition MAY contain one (and never more than one) of the following categories:

  - `l. a. c.`
  - `f.`
  - `m.`
- The category is always at the start of a definition
- The first definition starts from the begining, if there are more definitions, they start with `\\ n.` where 'n' is a number (could be more than one digit)

For the example I gave, the following definitions should be parsed:

1. (Category: `l.a.c.`) Buitre, alimoche. adj. Persona alelada. (Cornago). GOICOECHEA
2. (Category: `f.`) Persona torpe, despistada e irreflexiva.
3. (No category) Estar mirando a los abantos. fr. fig. Ser despistado, soñador, no apercibirse de la realidad. Autol. RUIZ.
4. (Category: `f.`) esto es una prueba

I am trying to make a regex to capture every definition (that is 0 or 1 category + meaning). This is what I have

```
(?:(m\.|l\. a\. c\.|f\.) )?(.*?) (?:$|(?:\/\/ \d+. (?:(m\.|l\. a\. c\.|f\.) )?(.*?))+)
```

I am testing it [here](https://regex101.com/r/gH2uD9/2) This is how I wrote it:

```
(?:
    (m\.|l\. a\. c\.|f\.)  <-- First: unnamed group containing the named group 
                                      for the category  and one space
)?
(.*?)                      <-- Named group for the meaning
(?:                        <-- Unnamed group for end of line OR another definition
   $                       <--- (end of line)
   |                       <--- (OR)
   (?:\/\/ \d+.            <--- (Definition separator & number)
       (?:(m\.|l\. a\. c\.|f\.) )?(.*?) <-- Another definition
   )+                                   <-- There may be more than one definition, so we add '+'
)
```

I have serveral problems:

- I am not sure why it does not work. It seems like the last capture group `(.*?)` is not expanding until the next `\\`. How can I fix it?
- The group `(m\.|l\. a\. c\.|f\.)` should be larger (there are more categories) How can I avoid repeating it?
- There are some repetition in the regex string that I gave, how can I avoid that?

This is my first non-trivial regex example, so any other comentaries about style, or improve in general are welcome.

My main question is ***why is my regex not working.*** (This is just to clarify...)

Comment: May be it is clear now?

Comment: The first dictionary example is great - would be nice to have some more lines to try a regex against.

Comment: Here there are some more lines (They may be other categories, though...) http://pastebin.com/STsq16i9

Comment: `(?:(m\.|l\. a\. c\.|f\.) )?(.*?)(?:$|(?:\/\/ \d+.) +)` Works a bit better for me, if you make it greedy. Not really sure why the original doesn't work, but as for the repetition you want to reduce I don't think there's much you can do about that.

Comment: Thanks for all the detail and explicitly pointing out you want to know why it isn't working. People tend to ignore that kind of question and just slap a completely new pattern into the asker's face (heck, even I do that sometimes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the last capture group is non-greedy.

```
(?:
    (m\.|l\. a\. c\.|f\.)
)?
(.*?)
(?:
   $
   |
   (?:\/\/ \d+.
       (?:(m\.|l\. a\. c\.|f\.) )?
       (.*?) <-- this is non-greedy.
   )
)+
```

Because of that, it will simply match the empty string. The `+` at the end of the pattern doesn't do anything because it already matched once, and that's enough to stop.

The fix is simple: Force the pattern to match the entire line. Just add `$` at the end.

```
(?:(m\.|l\. a\. c\.|f\.) )?(.*?) (?:$|(?:\/\/ \d+. (?:(m\.|l\. a\. c\.|f\.) )?(.*?)))+$
```

---

**EDIT:** It's not possible to capture each category and definition with a single regex. If you use a single pattern to match the entire string, each capture group will only contain the text it matched *last*, so you'll only be able to parse the last definition.

You can use this pattern to match a single definition.

```
(?:^| \/\/ \d\. )(?:(?P<category>m\.|l\. a\. c\.|f\.) )?(?P<definition>.*?)(?:$|(?= \/\/ \d\.))
```

Apply it to the string until it no longer finds a match to capture all definitions.

```
while (matcher.find()){
   ... do something
}
```

[Demo.](https://regex101.com/r/yE7bO2/1)

---

Detailed explanation of the pattern:

```
(?:
    ^ // match start of string
| // OR
     \/\/ \d\. // "\\ " literally, followed by a digit, a dot, and a space
)
(?:
    (?P<category> // in the named group "category", capture...
        m\.|l\. a\. c\.|f\. // one of "m.", "l. a. c.", "f."
    )  // and a space
)? // ...if possible.
(?P<definition> // in the named group "definition", capture...
    .*? // everything up to...
)
(?:
    $ // the end of the string
| // OR
    (?= // the start of the next definition. This needs to be enclosed in a lookahead assertion so as not to consume it.
         \/\/ \d\.
    ) 
)
```

Comment: That doesn't fix it, as you can see here https://regex101.com/r/gH2uD9/3 (I have named the groups). There are a lot of definitions not being captured

Comment: @Trollkemada: I guess I misunderstood what you were trying to achieve. I'll update my answer.

Comment: You missed the `+` after the digit (to allow more than one digit numbers) but otherwise great answer! Thanks for your effort.

Comment: Nevertheless, why this doesnot work? (the (?<name>X) is the syntax for named groups in Java 7) http://ideone.com/K65Fjw

Comment: You need to remove the `X` from the named groups. The `X` is just a place holder for the pattern that you want to match.